# Call a method from another class java

Tags: java

I have multiple classes, and am attempting to call a method in a different class.
This should work, but it gives errors:

```
TheMethods method = new TheMethods();
```

Java tells me that the constructor TheMethods() is undefined.
What I am doing wrong?

Edit:
I needed to pass a reference to my main class and initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you have a parameter `MCTag m`. If you are going to use this constructor you would need to do it like this:

```
TheMethods method = new TheMethods(MCTag m);
```

Constructors are like any other method and have to have the correct parameters in order for it to work correctly.

EDIT:
It would look something like this:

```
MCTag myTag; 
TheMethods method = new TheMethods(myTag); 
method.selectPlayer();
```

Comment: The `MCTag m` is the data type `MCTag` and `m` is just a variable. So you will need to pass in the local variable of the type `MCTag`.

Comment: Okay. And then reference that?

Comment: Yes, so it would look something like this: `MCTag myTag; TheMethods method = new TheMethods(myTag); method.selectPlayer(); `

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! Best of luck with your app/program!

Comment: That is because you need to assign the `MCTag` variable a value of the `MCTag` data type.

Answer (score 1):

The only constructor you provide on TheMethods is

```
    public TheMethods(MCTag m) {...
```

Which takes an MCTag parameter, and you are attempting to call a no-arg constructor which, as the compiler is telling you, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add the default constructor with no args

public TheMethods() {
    }

Comment: When you have to create a new TheMethods object, make sure that you are passing in a parameter of type mctag. That way, you will not encounter the error.

Answer (score 0):

the only ctor i see in your code is:

```
public TheMethods(MCTag m)
```

but you don't pass any values in your sample code here

there realy isnt any TheMethods() ctor defined

Answer (score -2):

to reference a *public* method in another class, call

```
Class.Method();
```